# Events called from Javascript library

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dom-events

I'm currently writing Javascript uploading library which I want to use across few websites, I have my own object `Data` which contain files, metadata etc.

`Data` has function called `.send()` which uploads `FormData` with `XMLHttpRequest`

My goal is to create progress bar with `EventListener` on `'progress'`. But I don't know which approach is correct, because I don't know how the place for progress bar will be named in HTML at every page. And I don't want to have any HTML code yet, only something what will let me customize that.

How I should manage that situation?

My current code:

```
Data.prototype.send = function() {
  'use strict';
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.file, this.name);
  if (this.property !== undefined) {
    formData.append('property', this.property);
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
    //What to do here?
  }, false);

  request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      //What to do here?
    }
  };
  request.open('POST', upload.php, true);
  request.send(formData);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a callback to your send() method is one possible solution. Then each page using the upload widget could receive progress events with which to update their UI.  You could also pre-process the events to return a simple percent complete. Both methods are shown in the example below.

Also, "onloadstart", "onprogress", and "onloadend" all return the same event type, but at different points in the upload cycle.  So it might be useful (as shown) to combine all three using a single handler.

From my experience, not all browsers return the same properties or at the same time in the upload cycle. So you may need to experiment a bit to make it work correctly. The more useful properties are: iscomputable, total, totalSize, loaded, position.  More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) on MDN.

```
Data.prototype.send = function( callback ) {

    // 1. forward raw event to page handler 

    request.upload.onloadstart = 
      request.upload.onprogress = 
        request.upload.onloadend = callback;

    // 2. alternative - process event and return percent to page handler

    request.upload.onloadstart = 
      request.upload.onprogress = 
        request.upload.onloadend = function(e) {

            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            if (typeof callback == 'function') callback( pc );

    }
```

Comment: I solved it with something similar to this: https://jsfiddle.net/lol2x/r82jevbt/ thanks for that callback idea :)